# Node.js/Express/Redis wait for only one message from channel

Tags: node.js, express, redis

I have a redis connection subscribed to a channel with a get request

```
app.get('/wait', function (req, res) {
    redisSub.on('message', function(channel, msg) {
        console.log('rcv: ' + msg);
    });
});
```

And later with a different get request I send the message

```
app.get('/done/:msg', function (req, res) {
    redisPub.publish('message', req.params.msg);
});
```

The problem is that I want that request to stop listening for messages once it gets it.  Or else when I go through again it will still be listening and will get the next message again.  I'm not sure how to remove the listener from itself once the message is received.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested but this should work,

```
var callback = function(channel, msg) {
    console.log('rcv: ' + msg);
    redisSub.removeListener('message', callback); 
}
redisSub.on('message', callback);
```